# Updated CSS not appearing in merged file

Tags: css, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-settings

A skin.css file has been updated on a DotNetNuke website, but the updated change to the file has not yet come through on the main css file.

Tried clearing the cache within DNN and no luck...

I'm not overly familiar with DNN and how it works, but isn't it supposed to get merged into the rest of the CSS files with the DependencyHandler.axd. This does not seem to have happened.

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

When you say it isn't showing up in the Main.CSS file, I am going to assume you are using the CDF functionality in the platform. If so, you can go to the Host/Host Settings page, and look for the Client Dependency Framework portion of the settings.

In those settings you can "increase" the version number, which should cause the files to be regenerated, you can also turn off CDF to allow DNN to just load the CSS and JS files normally which generally makes debugging things a little bit easier.